# Creating an array in excel cell from start and end number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a number array from the given start and end number. I have tried using the formula

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2))
```

which is not giving me the expected result.
I am expecting the result as `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

Please help

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Excel 2019 or ExcelO365?

Comment: @JvdV, MS Excel 2016

Comment: Then maybe easiest would be an `UDF` through `VBA`

Comment: Do you want to return an **array** as you write, or a **string** as you show.  Your formula returns the **array**: `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}`.  If you wish the elements to be comma separated, merely `TRANSPOSE(your_formula)`